# searching through database fails

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to look up the database table for people whose registered date equals 4-22.

My sql would look something similar like this

```
function GetUsers($dreg)
{
    $dt=(new DateTime($dreg))->format('Y-m-d');
    $result=$this->query("SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE dreg='$dt'");
    return ($this->getNumRows()>0)?$result:null;
}
```

However the sql turns out incorrect because I need to get only month and day when the employee registered not the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compare just day and month instead of the whole date:

```
function GetUsers($dreg)
{
    $dt=(new DateTime($dreg))->format('m-d');
    $result=$this->query("SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dreg, '%m-%d') = '$dt'");
    return ($this->getNumRows()>0)?$result:null;
}
```

Comment: @Dust, there was an error on the MySQL date format string, check the updated code.

Comment: thank you, you told me the function and way to use, the rest I will try to fix myself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert both sides of the date to strings then compare.